# Redirecting specific ip addresses to a different website. The hosting server is Apache

Tags: redirects, apache, ip-address

Redirecting specific IP addresses to a different website. The hosting server  is Apache.

I want certain visitors with specific IP address's to be redirected to a different website. I will be adding more over time.

I found:

```
#Redirect whole networks of IP addresses to an external URL
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} ^10\.20\.30 [OR]
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} ^125\.62
RewriteRule ^folder/(.*) http://anotherdomain.com/folder/$1 [R,L]
```

Is there any simpler way to do this?

Also, can I redirect 2 different IP addresses to different sites?

Why is ! added before the IP address on some examples of the above?

What does the /$1 do?

Does .htaccess mods work on ip6v addresses?

Comment: you are using 3 rows correct?

Comment: Your edits completely change the question being asked, and hence impacts the answer already received, so it's being rolled back. Please ask another question specific to redirecting IPv6 addresses.

Answer (score 2):

Something more like this for a range..

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} !^204\.246\.160\.([0-9]|1[0-9])
RewriteRule ^ http://www.domain.com%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

You can also use php, with something like this..

```
if ip = specific range
  redirect to site 1
else
 redirect to site 2
```

In response to your comment, use this..

**COPY ALL OF THIS AS IS..**

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^172\.56\.30\.223$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.cat.com/$1 [L,R=301]
```

Comment: `!=204\.246\.160\.([0-9]|1[0-9])` - Maybe a copy/paste error? But if you use the "lexicographically equal" operator (ie. `=` prefix) then the _CondPattern_ becomes a literal string, not a regex. So, this would need to be something like `!^204\.246\.160\.([0-9]|1[0-9])`

Comment: I think it's possibly not working on the single IP because it is pulling his proxy/router IP, but in regards to your comment, thank you as I did strip code above that was initially a range and did not change the aforementioned line. Thank you.